# record kinect data

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello

i have question about record kinect data.

when i record kinect data, i write command line

```
rosbag record /odom /camera/rgb/image_rect_color camera/depth_registered/image_raw /camera/rgb/camera_info /tf -O kinect
```

record is ok. but bag file is large. (5min record --> more 10GB)

but your bag file is smaller than my file.

For this demo, you will need the ROS bag demo_mapping.bag (295 MB, fixed camera TF 2016/06/28).
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B46akLGdg-uadXhLeURiMTBQU28&export=download

could u teach me how to write command line for record data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247422/record-kinect-data/) by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In that particular demo, the images were throttled at ~10 Hz and the compressed topics were recorded:

```
<!-- Throttling messages -->
  <group ns="camera">
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="data_throttle" args="load rtabmap_ros/data_throttle camera_nodelet_manager" output="screen">
      <param name="rate" type="double" value="10.0"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image_in"       to="rgb/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image_in"     to="depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info_in" to="rgb/camera_info"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image_out"       to="/data_throttled_image"/>
      <remap from="depth/image_out"     to="/data_throttled_image_depth"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info_out" to="/data_throttled_camera_info"/>
    </node>
  </group>
```

Record:

```
$ rosbag record /odom /data_throttled_image/compressed /data_throttled_image_depth/compressedDepth /data_throttled_camera_info /tf -O kinect
```

**Tip 1**

If you are using [freenect_launch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack/blob/8572761912ca03fd109e93bf8bc85bbc590d29ab/freenect_launch/launch/freenect.launch#L10), it may be more efficient to set `data_skip` instead of using the `data_throttle` nodelet above:

```
$ roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch depth_registration:=true data_skip:=3
$ rosbag record /odom /camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressedDepth /camera/rgb/camera_info /tf -O kinect
```

**Tip 2**

If you don't want to save compressed images in the rosbag, you may compress to rosbag after the recording to save some space when storing it:

```
$ rosbag compress kinect.bag
```

Make sure to decompress before replaying it:

```
$ rosbag decompress kinect.bag
$ rosbag play --clock kinect.bag
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0